# Telling grep to treat N as [ATCG]

Tags: fastq, trimming, grep

Okay so I'm using grep to try and get a preview of some trimming operations that are not going as expected..
Lets say that my sequence in the FastQ file is: ATNGCNATCG

What I want to do is..

`grep "ATCGCTATCG" my.fastq`

..and match the sequence given above

Surely there is some way or some existing tool that I can use besides doing:
`grep "[A|N][T|N][C|N][G|N][C|N]...etc."`

Comment: Your fix is going to match NNNNN, ANNNC and etc. - are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Technically, no it's not what I want, but as this is just trying to get a picture for what's going on under the hood I think it wont be a problem :)

Comment: Note that this will fail if the target sequence is split across multiple fastq lines. The fastq format does not _require_ only one line of sequence per entry, you can have multiple ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to stick to `grep`, use a scripting language such as Perl to generate the regex programmatically. For example:

```
perl -le 'print join "", map "[${_}N]", split //, $ARGV[0];' ATCGCTATCG
```

Prints:

```
[AN][TN][CN][GN][CN][TN][AN][TN][CN][GN]
```

You can use it in `grep` like so:

```
grep '[AN][TN][CN][GN][CN][TN][AN][TN][CN][GN]' <<< ATNGCNATCG
```

Prints:

```
ATNGCNATCG
```

If that works for you, you could make it into a little bash function that also runs the `grep`. Add these lines to your `~/.bashrc`:

```bash
grepN(){
    seq="$1"
    file="$2"
    pattern=$(perl -le 'print join "", map "[${_}N]", split //, $ARGV[0];' "$seq")
    grep "$pattern" "$file"
}
```

You can now run

```
grepN ATCGCTATCG my.fastq
```

Of course, this is not a good idea since the sequence might be in different lines, but that's what you were doing originally.

Comment: Awesome, I'll try this out. It will at least save me the time typing out all those N's hah.

Comment: It does involve one extra step, but saves me tons of time and gets me the data I need! Thanks!

Comment: @RPINerd I edited Timur's very clever solution to add a shell function that you can use to do the whole thing in one step. I hope you don't mind, Timur, please let me know if you'd rather I posted a separate answer. It just seemed like a trivial extension of yours and you did all the work so...

Comment: @terdon Your edits and suggestions are always welcome! Thank you.